# Boolean Preconditions

Tags: alloy

I am a beginner with alloy working on some basic models.  I am trying to use preconditions for a function.  However, I would like to use Boolean results instead of the idea of contained in a set as the book mentions.  Is this possible? If so, what is the best way to implement this?

Example:
Function(x,y,z) -> z
pre: pred(x) /\ pred(y)
post: pred(z)

Thanks,
Seth

Comment: Are you asking how to have a Boolean variable in a signature?

Comment: Please provide the code you've written and explain what you've tried so far. Include any errors you get. See this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get a detailed explanation for how to write good questions that will be more likely to get helpful answers.

Comment: Hello,
Sorry I havent written any code yet. I was doing more reading and considering potential applications.  Hopefully, my example helps describe what i mean a bit better.

Example:
Function(x,y,z) -> z
pre: pred(x) /\ pred y
post: pred(z)